# не подрубается проект

Tags: reactjs

вчера запускал проект все работало сегодня пытаюсь запустить сломался ничего не редактировал не изменял у знакомого точно также сломался проект у меня была последняя рабочая копия запустил её на след день точно также все доломалось

PS C:\Users\toxsyn\Desktop\саня скиба\fronted> npm start

> client@0.1.0 start C:\Users\toxsyn\Desktop\саня скиба\fronted
> react-scripts start

Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx update-browserslist-db@latest
Why you should do it regularly: https://github.com/browserslist/update-db#readme
Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.

- options.allowedHosts[0] should be a non-empty string.
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  npm ERR! errno 1
  npm ERR! client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
  npm ERR! Exit status 1
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 start script.
  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\toxsyn\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2024-02-01T08_48_37_296Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\toxsyn\Desktop\саня скиба\fronted>

пробовал проверить пэкедж жсон все выгядит рабочим

[image: пакегежсон]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: `npx update-browserslist-db@latest` запускали?

Comment: Возможно, обновление браузеров тому причина, особенно если build проходит

Comment: пробовал запускать npx update-browserslist-db@latest была ошибка update npm or call npx update-browserslist-db@latest обновил, вызвал и все равно такая же ошибка попробовал запустить заново = не включается та же ошибка что и билась

Comment: https://pastebin.com/vhv6QXrt вот логи